# Disable Android Browser's (WebKit's) input focus glow

Tags: html, css, android-browser, mobile-webkit

I'm trying to style inputs for a webpage.
When the webpage is viewed on Android 4.0.4 default browser, focusing on an input applies a blue glow.

Idle:

[image]

Input focused:

[image]

I want to disable that blue border (and make my own one), but if i set `-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only`, the input will lose its type (HTML `type="number"`) and won't slide up a number keyboard (like on the screenshot).

CSS Properties tried:

1. `-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only` with `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)`
2. `outline: none`
3. `border: 0`
4. `box-shadow: none`

Is it possible to disable this WebKit feature yet keep the number keyboard?
Thanks ;)

Comment: I think its `outline:none;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ali, i have tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: Is this Chrome or the previous Android browser? I'm not sure when the switch was made. If Chrome, have you tried connecting it to a desktop or laptop and debugging in Chrome on that computer. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 1):

Try this :) (change to what ever color/opacity you want

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my CSS already has `* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }`.